# Slickgrid define grid model for sortable categories of rows

Tags: slickgrid

I'm a new to slickgrid, and not sure how to display the data as attached with the screenshot below. I read [grouping example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping), but it's grouped by an existing column and not sortable. In the example, each category has multiple items with prices, and it's sorted by **Category name** and price.

Any help with displaying the data so that category is sortable is greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Lanny

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time with the examples, I learned that I can define what I want to display in columns obj. In data obj, I can have as many properties as I want.

In the code example, the first column is the actual product, but the name is Category, it's kind of confusing but it's a business decision. After I added all the data, I added the category name in product column and set colspan to "*" before each group of products, so it expands to all columns. I'm sure that SlickGrid DataView group has a better solution than this, right now I haven't gotten that far. If someone can elaborate more on how to use DataView, I appreciate it.

code example: http://jsbin.com/efujox/2/

```
columns = [
    {id:"product", name:"Category", field:"product"},
    {id:"price", name:"Price", field:"price"},
    {id:"date", name:"Date", field:"date"}
];

data =[
    {id: 'p1', product: 'Item 332', category:'Category XBC', price: 5.99, date: '6/19/11'},
    {id: 'p2', product: 'Item 12', category:'Category XBC', price: 6.99, date: '8/20/11'},
    {id: 'p3', product: 'Item nVV', category:'Category CXV', price: 4.99, date: '5/11/12'},
    {id: 'p4', product: 'Item dcA', category:'Category CXV', price: 9.42, date: '8/11/11'}
];
```